# What is codeStyleConfig xml file in codeStyles of idea folder?

Tags: android, coding-style

I updated my Android Studio as `3.1.2` and `codeStyleConfig` xml was created automatically in `.idea` folder like this.

```
<component name="ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration">
  <state>
    <option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="Default" />
  </state>
</component>
```

I'm wondering what **PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE** is and **Default** means. Is there anyone to know about this?

Answer (score 15):

When working in a large team, you can version control this file and change your style settings in Preferences > Editor > Code Style to read from that file instead of from your IDE. That way, everyone shares style settings and everyone can autoformat without having to worry about conflicting with formatting differences in other people's branches.

[image: Screenshot of how to change code style preferences]

Comment: So what is the meaning of the `Default`? Is it `!Project`?

Comment: @JinKwon `Default` is what's defined in `.idea/codeStyles/codeStyleConfig.xml`