# Do I have to add the codeStyleConfig.xml and encondings.xml files to Git from the .idea directory?

Tags: git, android-studio

I cloned a new repository from the master branch and I launched the project for the first time on Android studio, a window appears that asks me if I add the files of the .idea directory such as codeStyleConfig.xml and encodings.xml so I do not know if I should ignore them or not, I'll be grateful for your help, thanks.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2):

If there are other developers working on the project, you should have `codeStyleConfig.xml` in git, so you can all have the same code style. If you are and will be the only developer on the project, you don't need it. You can find more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445816/6835732).

Also, looks like Google does that, too -> [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/.gitignore) (notice the `!` in the beginning of the line for `codeStyleConfig.xml`).

What is `encodings.xml` you can find out in [this answer](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360002151039/comments/360000295160). I say that you should have it in git regardless of whether you work alone or not.